# String formatting in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, string-formatting

I want to get the phone number from a customer but I want it to be seen as `()__-__` like format and when customer enters the numbers it will not be disappeared and I will like get the result as `(555) 555-55` .

How would I go about doing that? Is there a specific control I should be using?

Comment: how is the body of the question in ANY way related to the (original) title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a MaskedTextBox control. There isn't one out of the box, but there are plenty of them out there if you search around. For example, check out [the WPF extended toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox).

Example usage for a US phone number with area code, from the above link:

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox x:Name="_maskedTextBox"
      Mask="(000) 000-0000" ValueDataType="{x:Type s:String}" />
```

Here, the zeroes represent a required numeric digit. Without any data, the control will render like this:

```
(___) ___-____
```

Any character in the mask other than a special token will be rendered as a literal part of the mask, as with the parentheses in the above example. Here is a list of mask tokens. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx), which is for the old Windows forms MaskedTextBox and not WPF, but the toolkit version follows the same conventions, as do most other WPF versions.

> `0`
> Digit, required. This element will accept any single digit between 0 and 9.
>
> `9`
> Digit or space, optional.
>
> `#`
> Digit or space, optional. If this position is blank in the mask, it will be rendered as a space in the Text property. Plus (+) and minus (-) signs are allowed.
>
> `L`
> Letter, required. Restricts input to the ASCII letters a-z and A-Z. This mask element is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]` in regular expressions.
>
> `?`
> Letter, optional. Restricts input to the ASCII letters a-z and A-Z. This mask element is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]?` in regular expressions.
>
> `&`
> Character, required. If the AsciiOnly property is set to true, this element behaves like the `L` element.
>
> `C`
> Character, optional. Any non-control character. If the AsciiOnly property is set to true, this element behaves like the `?` element.
>
> `A`
> Alphanumeric, optional. If the AsciiOnly property is set to true, the only characters it will accept are the ASCII letters a-z and A-Z.
>
> `a`
> Alphanumeric, optional. If the AsciiOnly property is set to true, the only characters it will accept are the ASCII letters a-z and A-Z.
>
> `.`
> Decimal placeholder. The actual display character used will be the decimal symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.
>
> `,`
> Thousands placeholder. The actual display character used will be the thousands placeholder appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.
>
> `:`
> Time separator. The actual display character used will be the time symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.
>
> `/`
> Date separator. The actual display character used will be the date symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.
>
> `$`
> Currency symbol. The actual character displayed will be the currency symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.
>
> `<`
> Shift down. Converts all characters that follow to lowercase
>
> `>`
> Shift up. Converts all characters that follow to uppercase.
>
> `|`
> Disable a previous shift up or shift down.
>
> `\`
> Escape. Escapes a mask character, turning it into a literal. "\" is the escape sequence for a backslash.